# jquery - right click and appear flash menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, menu

I'm creating a website in HTML, CSS, PHP, JS... but I would like that when I click in a specific part of the website it would appear the typical flash menu:

- Configuration
- Global Configuration
- About Adobe Flash... (version)

Actually, the specific part where I want to do that isn't flash, I only want to make it look like Flash. So I looked for "custom right click website", but all the custom menus are pretty different from the real flash menu I want.

Is there anyway to do this easily or some code that closes pretty much to what I'm searching?

Comment: The ones you looked up  --> They may look different than what you want, but you are able to style them so that they more closely resemble what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a screenshot of the flash menu, save it as a png.

```
<img src="yourScreenshot.png" id="myScreenshot" style="display:none; position:absolute;" />
```

and then on mouse click

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
            $('#myScreenshot').css('left',event.pageX).css('top', event.pageY).show();
            break;
    }
});
```